# Displaying index instead of "__name__label__ *"

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin

Using sonata admin Bundle And I have A form to Define the A "Question" model, I have an attribute "choices" which is a collection :

```
->add('choices', 'collection', 
array('allow_add' => true,'allow_delete' => true, 'block_name' => false, 
'delete_empty' => true,  'label' => 'choices'))
```

When I add a choice The label wrote in his top is "_name__label__*", I need to change it to the choice index, anyone found a solution for this ? thank you